# Ignore if-else ladder and implements strategic design pattern

Tags: javascript, java, design-patterns, typescript, strategy-pattern

I am trying to implement strategic design pattern .

I have simple if-else ladder as below:

```
       if(dataKeyinresponse === 'year') {
           bsd = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
           nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        } else if(dataKeyinresponse === 'quarter') {
            let tempDate = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).add(2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            // nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).add(3, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            nestedbed = new Date(moment(tempDate).endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        } else if(dataKeyinresponse === 'month') {
            nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        } else if(dataKeyinresponse === 'week') {
            //Relying more on the ES start date for week
            nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).weekday(7).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

        } else {
          // bed = bucketStartDate;
          nestedbed = new Date(item['key']);
        }
```

and i implemented strategic pattern upon it:

```
interface emptyBucketInterface {
    fnGetEmptyBuckets();
}
class year implements emptyBucketInterface {
    fnGetEmptyBuckets() {
        bsd = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).startOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
        nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).endOf('year').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        return {
            "bsd": bsd,
            "nestedbed": nestedbed
        };
    }
}
class quarter implements emptyBucketInterface {
    fnGetEmptyBuckets() {
        let tempDate = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).add(2, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        nestedbed = new Date(moment(tempDate).endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        return {
            "tempDate": tempDate,
            "nestedbed": nestedbed
        };
    }
}
class month implements emptyBucketInterface {
    fnGetEmptyBuckets() {
        nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        return {
            "nestedbed": nestedbed
        };
    }
}
class week implements emptyBucketInterface {
    fnGetEmptyBuckets() {
        nestedbed = new Date(moment(new Date(item['key'])).weekday(7).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        return {
            "nestedbed": nestedbed
        };
    }
}
```

but i am confused as how to invoke a particular class based on condition

Like in above if-else ladder it checks for `dataKeyinresponse` value and then execute some statements

but here in strategic pattern how to see for the condition and then execute that class.

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Seems like you have changed the way the returning object are created, but not actually changed anytting with regard to your if-else ladder.  You might be better off with a switch statement, or an object with functions named 'year','quarter','month'....

Comment: ... `actions[datakeyinresponse]()`  ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat 
That code is written in typescript

Comment: @jdphenix

Could you please provide me the answer because i didn't understand ur comment

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of strategy pattern:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private final Map<String, EmptyBucketInterface> strategies = new HashMap<String, EmptyBucketInterface>();

    public SomeClass() {
        strategies.put("year", new Year());
        strategies.put("quarter", new Quarter());
        strategies.put("month", new Month());
        strategies.put("week", new Week());
    }

    public void doAction(String action) {
        strategies.get(action).fnGetEmptyBuckets();
    }
}
```

You may take a look at this: https://www.tomasmalmsten.com/2011/01/create-factory-strategies-ifs/ to encapsulate the strategies creation in a factory.

**Advice**: You should name your classes with a capitalized first-letter `emptyBucketInterface` => `EmptyBucketInterface`